# Syntax error in flask MySQL LIKE concat query

Tags: python, mysql, web, flask

I'm using MySQL with Python Flask and trying to do a search query with LIKE concat however I am getting a Syntax error with it or a Type Error if I use different marks around my symbols.

```
name_search = form.name.data
cursor.execute('SELECT id, name, surname FROM users WHERE surname LIKE CONCAT ('%', '%s', '%')', [name_search])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the percentage signs within the variable

```
cursor.execute("SELECT id, name, surname FROM users 
    WHERE surname LIKE '{}'".format("%" + name_search + "%"))
```

Comment: Was able to use this to get to where I needed thank you!